# Returning rows even when query value is not found

Tags: sql

I have a query like below in SQL. I would like to return `Item` with `quantity: 0` even when it does not return any data (i.e. 590209, 590212 does not exist in my records). I have probably 10000 records I need to return. Any idea how to do it?

```
SELECT [Item] ,[Qty] 
  FROM Table
  where Item in (590209,590210,590211,590212,590213)
```

Results should be like

```
Item     Qty
590209   0
590210   3
590211   1
590212   0
590213   1
```

Comment: which db you are using??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below

```
select t.Item,t1.Qty from 
(
select 590209  as Item
union all
select 590210 
union all
select 590211 
union all
select 590212
 union all
select 590213
) t left join your_table t1
  on t.Item=t1.Item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below to return "Item" with quantity 0

```
SELECT [Item] ,[Qty] 
FROM Table 
where Qty = 0
```